# How to add a new value to the attribute with a comma on each click and not overwrite the attribute value?

Tags: jquery

After clicking on **"li.ui-menu-item"** I read the values from its child elements and transfer them to the attribute of the element `$(".field--name-field-pms-colors")`

```
$("li.ui-menu-item").click(function() {

  const $viewsFieldPmsColorData = $(this).find(".views-field-pms-color-data");
  const $viewsFieldNameContent = $(this).find(".views-field-name .field-content").text();
  const imageSrc = $viewsFieldPmsColorData.data("src");
  const hex = $viewsFieldPmsColorData.data("hex");

  const additionalColorData = {
    [$viewsFieldNameContent]: {
      'name': $viewsFieldNameContent,
      'hex': hex,
      'src': imageSrc
    }
  };

  const additionalColorDataString = JSON.stringify(additionalColorData).replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
  $(".field--name-field-pms-colors").attr('data-custom-attribute', additionalColorDataString);
});
```

The problem is that each subsequent click overwrites the value of the attribute, instead, you need to add new values to the attribute with a comma after each click.

sandbox:
https://jsfiddle.net/gikooo/1tn3maLc/14/

at the first click on one `<li>`, the attribute looks like this:

```
<div class="field--name-field-pms-colors" data-custom-attribute="{&amp;quot;1925c&amp;quot;:{&amp;quot;name&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;1925c&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;hex&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;#FE464C&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;src&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;&amp;quot;}}"</div>
```

at the second click on another `<li>`, the attribute looks like this:

```
<div class="field--name-field-pms-colors" data-custom-attribute="{&quot;425c&quot;:{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;425c&quot;,&quot;hex&quot;:&quot;#57586E&quot;,&quot;src&quot;:&quot;&quot;}}"</div>
```

this is approximately how the attribute should look if there were two clicks on different `<li>`:

```
<div class="field--name-field-pms-colors" data-custom-attribute="{&quot;425c&quot;:{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;425c&quot;,&quot;hex&quot;:&quot;#57586E&quot;,&quot;src&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;116c&quot;:{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;116c&quot;,&quot;hex&quot;:&quot;#FCCA11&quot;,&quot;src&quot;:&quot;&quot;}}"</div>
```

Comment: Get the existing attribute first when determining the new attribute?

Comment: If you're using `data-` and don't need specific css (which seems unlikely as the values are dynamic) then you *should* be using `.data("custom-attribute")` - in which case you just store the data as-is (not JSON'd) then read it, add to it, and store it back